# Android: obtaining uuid of a bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I need UUID of a bluetooth device to connect to it, but i don't know much about uuid. Is it specific to each device and how to know what is `device's uuid`. Can it be done using code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be more explicit when you make your question. Do you want to connect to a BT device, or you are already connected and you want to use a particular service?

If you want to just connect to the device you need the BT address (`like a MAC`).

The UUID are related to the services offered by the BT device: http://www.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/UUID.html Here you have a list of UUIDs.

Comment: Something, that may help, i will aad it here as comment, becuase googled this answer. If your BT device is connected to PC and is using 'Standard serial over Bluetooth link', you meay find it's UUID by going to Device Manager, then go to properties of this connection, and then in details, from scroll list select Hardware Ids. You will find something like this:
BTHENUM\{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_LOCALMFG&0000
where {00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} is uuid.

Answer (score -4):

Generate `UUID` of your phone by using adb shell, sdptool browse command