# How to make a bluetooth connection in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to connect to this device: http://www.rhydolabz.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=479

I tried using the `BluetoothChat` class from the samples. But it did not work. It says `unable to connect device`.

Then I tried to use the following code within try catch

```
        // Create a Socket connection: need the server's UUID number
Method m = d.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { int.class });
socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(d, 1);
socket.connect();
Log.d("WCAM", ">>Client connectted");
inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
socket.close();
Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and I get the following error

```
04-18 20:45:01.660: W/System.err(6780): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord [int]
04-18 20:45:01.660: W/System.err(6780):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
04-18 20:45:01.660: W/System.err(6780):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
04-18 20:45:01.660: W/System.err(6780):     at com.xpleria.wirelesscontroller.Login.onStart(Login.java:90)
04-18 20:45:01.660: W/System.err(6780):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
04-18 20:45:01.670: W/System.err(6780):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
04-18 20:45:01.670: W/System.err(6780):     at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:4526)
04-18 20:45:01.670: W/System.err(6780):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4531)
04-18 20:45:01.670: W/System.err(6780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
04-18 20:45:01.670: W/System.err(6780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
04-18 20:45:01.670: W/System.err(6780):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1173)
04-18 20:45:01.670: W/System.err(6780):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 20:45:01.680: W/System.err(6780):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 20:45:01.680: W/System.err(6780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-18 20:45:01.680: W/System.err(6780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 20:45:01.680: W/System.err(6780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 20:45:01.680: W/System.err(6780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
04-18 20:45:01.680: W/System.err(6780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
04-18 20:45:01.680: W/System.err(6780):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any way how I can modify my code..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of notes:

a) It's not obvious what is the class of variable d. I assume it's BluetoothDevice

b) If my assumption from 1) is correct, it can't find a method createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(int), because actualy method is [createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID).](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29)

c) It's not clear to me, why do you use reflection to get to this method. You can call it on your object directly.

d) There was a piece documentation which says: "Hint: If you are connecting to a Bluetooth serial board then try using the well-known SPP UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB. However if you are connecting to an Android peer then please generate your own unique UUID.". I think it could be applicable to you.

**Update 1**

Regarding using directly.

You code should be

```
 d.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(someUUID);
```

since createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord is a method of BluetoothDevice.

Regarding UUID.Take a look at this:

[Android: obtaining uuid of a bluetooth device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949509/android-obtaining-uuid-of-a-bluetooth-device)

[Android: How do bluetooth UUIDs work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964342/android-how-do-bluetooth-uuids-work)

Comment: yes `d` is a BluetoothDevice. I'm not sure what this UUID means. What should I use for my device?
And actually I pulled out parts of code from other projects. That's how it was in them. If I have to use it directly, how do I use it?

Comment: if I use `socket = createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);` directly, it gives me an error saying, `The method createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID) is undefined for the type Login Login.java`

Comment: using this throws `java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1`