# Bluetooth Server Android - Client Java Bluecove. UUID?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluecove

I'm writing an application to communicate between my smartphone and a computer using a bluetooth device.

I'm using [Bluecove](http://bluecove.org/index.html) to manage the bluetooth on the computer, and the android API for my android device.

However, when I'm debugging, nothing happens. I think that the problem is that the UUID is wrong. I'm not sure how to get the devices to identify each other, in order to establish a connection.

I have read some other "questions" about those tags, but what I've tried didn't fix my problem:

- [Simple Bluetooth data receiver Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164138/simple-bluetooth-data-receiver-android)
- [Android: obtaining uuid of a bluetooth device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949509/android-obtaining-uuid-of-a-bluetooth-device)
- Etc...

Here's what I've written so far:

1. For tho android (Server) (This is the function that will make the connection)

   public void connectSocket(){
       blueAdapter.cancelDiscovery(); // Cancel discovery because it'll slow down the connection

   ```
   final BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;
   BluetoothServerSocket sSocket= null;
   try{
       sSocket = blueAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("BluetoothJANE", MY_UUID);
   }catch(IOException e){}
   serverSocket = sSocket;

   Thread acceptThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           BluetoothSocket socket = null;
           while(true){
               try{
                   socket = serverSocket.accept();
               }catch(IOException e){
                   break;
               }
               if(socket != null){
                   try{
                       iStream = socket.getInputStream();
                       oStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                   } catch(IOException e){}
               }
           }
       }
   });
   acceptThread.start();
   ```

   }
2. For java app on PC (This is the constructor of the class (it's on an independent thread) that will manage the bluetooth connection)

   public ModuleBluetooth() {

   ```
   StreamConnectionNotifier notifier = null;
   StreamConnection connection = null;

   try {
       blueDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
       blueDevice.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);

       String url = "btspp://localhost:" + MY_UUID.toString()
               + ";name=RemoteBluetooth";
       notifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(url);

   } catch (BluetoothStateException e) {
       System.out
               .println("ModuleBluetooth: Error getting the bluetooth device");
   } catch (IOException e) {
   }
   System.out.println("waiting for connection...");
   try {
       connection = notifier.acceptAndOpen();
       System.out.println("Conenction created");
   } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("Can not create the connection");
   }
   ```

   }

Could somebody please help me? Any thoughts would be very much appreciated.

I have also tried to use some functions to acquire the UUID (in android) such as, [fetchUuidsWithSdp][2] (and the related functions) but eclipse doesn't recognize that functions (It seems that they don't exist in "my" API).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#fetchUuidsWithSdp%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example, http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/ . I also had problem related to UUID, in this example, Converting UUID to **00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB** worked out of the box. See this link: http://www.avetana-gmbh.de/avetana-gmbh/produkte/doc/javax/bluetooth/UUID.html

Comment: Thanks!I also read those pages, but I skipped the sentence where he said that he's code (on android) was based on the BluetoothChat sample!  Thanks agains! I'm so pleased

Comment: Finally I manage the problem. It was that In the example the JAVA code was acting like a server as android does. But I need to program the JAVA code as a client.  I used this example: http://www.miniware.net/mobile/articles/viewarticle.php?id=22

Comment: @Bardo91 It was in archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20130628121926/www.miniware.net/mobile/articles/viewarticle.php?id=22